# FluentConfigurationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

FluentConfigurationException was unhandled

An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

My SessionFactory method:

```
_sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 // 
                              .ConnectionString(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=testdb1;Uid=dev;Pwd=123;"))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                                   .AddFromAssemblyOf<User>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                .Create(true, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The inner exception is:

> Unable to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle' during configuration of proxy factory class.
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> - The NHibernate.Bytecode provider assembly was not deployed.
> - The typeName used to initialize the 'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory section is not well formed.
>
> Solution:
>
> Confirm that your deployment folder contains one of the following assemblies:
>
> NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.dll
>
> NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll

I am testing things out in a console application.  My console app references my Data project that has all my nhibernate entities/mappings and sessionfactory code.

The Data project has the following in the /bin/debug folder:

```
Castle.core.dll, FluentNHibernate.dll, Iesi.COllection.dll, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll, NHibernate.dll
```

I downloaded all my .dll's from http://fluentnhibernate.org/ today (so it's fluent 1.2 using nhibernate 3.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add a reference to NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll to your console app.

Comment: Correct.  The NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle reference must be added to the entry point of the application.  If it's a Console app, then the console app project.  If it's a web app, then the web app project, etc.

Comment: i already have NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle in my project still same error persists. Can you please suggest any other scenario possible for this?